# SQL Plus with error error checking directory existence during ADR initialization but directory exists

Tags: sqlplus, oracle19c

I'm new to Oracle. I have installed it and I'm trying to Create a user in SQL plus. I used the following instructions:

```
-- 1. In The SQL Plus command prompt, enter user-name as sqlplus / as sysdba.
-- 2. Press Enter.
-- 3. In the Enter Password prompt, press Enter to log in without a password.
--    Note: The Connected to 19c database: message appears.
```

But then I restarted my computer because I was at the same time installing another software.

After that, trying to continue with SQL plus, I did the same procedure and got the following message: Connected to an idle instance. Instead to Connected to 19c database.

Then I read that shouting down the database and starting it up again would work. And I shouted it down but then when I tried to start it up I got this error:

```
--SQL> startup
--ORA-48173: error checking directory existence during ADR initialization 
--[C:\app\client\ivoespin\diag\rdbms\orcl]
--ORA-48187: specified directory does not exist
--OSD-00002: additional error information
--O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.
```

But I checked and the directory exists with an orcl folder and a i_1.mif file in it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you set the ORACLE_SID environment parameter before running sqlplus? What is the SID of your database?

Comment: You do not need to start the database, it usually is on autostart. You are better off installing a tool like sqldevloper than to fiddle around with SQL*plus.